# ffmpeg-php to create thumbnail of video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to use this script to create thumbnail of a video using **ffmpeg**. At first I used `phpinfo();` and I found ffmpeg is installed on my server.

Then I copied **ffmpeg-php** onto my server and run the test file

I got to know that many function are working on my server

I got output like this

**Output:-**

```
Functions available in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so extension:

Methods available in class ffmpeg_movie:
__construct
getduration
getframecount
getframerate
getfilename
getcomment
gettitle
getauthor
getartist
getcopyright
getalbum
getgenre
getyear
gettracknumber
getframewidth
getframeheight
getframenumber
getpixelformat
getbitrate
hasaudio
hasvideo
getnextkeyframe
getframe
getvideocodec
getaudiocodec
getvideostreamid
getaudiostreamid
getaudiochannels
getaudiosamplerate
getaudiobitrate
getvideobitrate
getpixelaspectratio
getpixelaspectratio
getvideobitrate
getaudiobitrate
getaudiosamplerate
getaudiochannels
getaudiostreamid
getvideostreamid
getaudiocodec
getvideocodec
getframe
getnextkeyframe
hasvideo
hasaudio
getbitrate
getpixelformat
getframenumber
getframeheight
getframewidth
gettracknumber
getyear
getgenre
getalbum
getcopyright
getartist
getauthor
gettitle
getcomment
getfilename
getframerate
getframecount
getduration
__construct
```

I wrote this code and tried any possible path to assign `$ffmpeg;`

```
<?php

    $thumb_stdout;
    $retval=0;
    $ffmpeg = '/home/lib/ffmpeg';

// change "demo.mpg" to your mpg file name!
$video  = dirname(__FILE__) . 'demo.mpg';

// change "demo.jpg" to whichever name you like or don't
// for this example, the name of the output jpg file does not matter
$image  = dirname(__FILE__) . 'demo.jpg';

$second = 1;

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video 2>&1";
if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', '$cmd', $time)) {
    $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
    $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
}

//$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -r 1 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:01 -s 250x250 -f image2 $image";
echo $cmd;
exec($cmd);
//$return = '$cmd';

echo '<br>done!';
?>
```

Comment: The problem is the script is not working bro.

Comment: Then please supply more information, bro. Any error messages? Does the command work from the command line?

Comment: No It just echos out my $cmd variable and done! at the last!!!  No errors nothing

Comment: At least try `echo shell_exec($cmd)` to see what's going on.

Comment: No change bro...Thanks for your comments...I tried all possible code with shell_exec($cmd);...But I am still in prob bro...

Comment: Please Help me I would appreciate any kind of Answers....

Comment: Try this post http://forum.coppermine-gallery.net/index.php?topic=38774.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last I got the code thanks to ***Anubhaw***.Your link helped lot.Try this code.

```
            //thumb path should be added in the below code
            //test for thumb
            $dir_img='uploads/';
            $mediapath='123.jpg';
            $file_thumb=create_movie_thumb($dir_img.$mediapath,$mediapath,$mediaid);

            $name_file=explode(".",$mediapath);
            $imgname="thumb_".$name_file[0].".jpg";     

            /*
              Function to create video thumbnail using ffmpeg
            */
            function create_movie_thumb($src_file,$mediapath,$mediaid)
            {
                global $CONFIG, $ERROR;

                $CONFIG['ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/'; // Change the path according to your server.
                $dir_img='uploads/';
                $CONFIG['fullpath'] = $dir_img."thumbs/";

                $src_file = $src_file;
                $name_file=explode(".",$mediapath);
                $imgname="thumb_".$name_file[0].".jpg";
                $dest_file = $CONFIG['fullpath'].$imgname;

                if (preg_match("#[A-Z]:|\\\\#Ai", __FILE__)) {
                    // get the basedir, remove '/include'
                    $cur_dir = substr(dirname(__FILE__), 0, -8);
                    $src_file = '"' . $cur_dir . '\\' . strtr($src_file, '/', '\\') . '"';
                    $ff_dest_file = '"' . $cur_dir . '\\' . strtr($dest_file, '/', '\\') . '"';
                } else {
                    $src_file = escapeshellarg($src_file);
                    $ff_dest_file = escapeshellarg($dest_file);
                }

                $output = array();

                if (eregi("win",$_ENV['OS'])) {
                    // Command to create video thumb
                    $cmd = "\"".str_replace("\\","/", $CONFIG['ffmpeg_path'])."ffmpeg\" -i ".str_replace("\\","/" ,$src_file )." -an -ss 00:00:05 -r 1 -vframes 1 -y ".str_replace("\\","/" ,$ff_dest_file);
                    exec ("\"$cmd\"", $output, $retval);

                } else {
                    // Command to create video thumb
                    $cmd = "{$CONFIG['ffmpeg_path']}ffmpeg -i $src_file -an -ss 00:00:05 -r 1 -vframes 1 -y $ff_dest_file";
                    exec ($cmd, $output, $retval);

                }


                if ($retval) {
                    $ERROR = "Error executing FFmpeg - Return value: $retval";
                    if ($CONFIG['debug_mode']) {
                        // Re-execute the command with the backtick operator in order to get all outputs
                        // will not work if safe mode is enabled
                        $output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
                        $ERROR .= "<br /><br /><div align=\"left\">Cmd line : <br /><span style=\"font-size:120%\">" . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($cmd)) . "</span></div>";
                        $ERROR .= "<br /><br /><div align=\"left\">The ffmpeg program said:<br /><span style=\"font-size:120%\">";
                        $ERROR .= nl2br(htmlspecialchars($output));
                        $ERROR .= "</span></div>";
                    }
                    @unlink($dest_file);
                    return false;
                }

                $return = $dest_file;
                //@chmod($return, octdec($CONFIG['default_file_mode'])); //silence the output in case chmod is disabled
                return $return;
            }
```

**Enjoy Coding**

with regards,

***Wasim***

Comment: could you look at my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189948/ffmpeg-is-not-creating-screenshot-from-video

Comment: The eregi function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0 but you can use preg_match

Answer (score 5):

Looked over the code, made it simpler and runnable, maybe this helps some of you.

```
class VideoTile
{
    public static function createMovieThumb($srcFile, $destFile = "test.jpg")
    {
        // Change the path according to your server.
        $ffmpeg_path = 'D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\';

        $output = array();

        $cmd = sprintf('%sffmpeg -i %s -an -ss 00:00:05 -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %s', 
            $ffmpeg_path, $srcFile, $destFile);

        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) == 'WIN'))
            $cmd = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $cmd);
        else
            $cmd = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $cmd);

        exec($cmd, $output, $retval);

        if ($retval)
            return false;

        return $destFile;
    }
}
```

Usage is

```
$file = VideoTile::createMovieThumb("../video3.mp4");
```