# create thumbnail from video in ffmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have download ffmpeg from this [link](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.5.3.tar.bz2) then extract to my localhost path:

> C:\wamp\www\ffmpeg-2.5.3\ffmpeg-2.5.3

Then create a file: test.php in above path and write this code:

```
// where ffmpeg is located 
$ffmpeg = 'http://localhost/ffmpeg-2.5.3/ffmpeg-2.5.3'; 
/*//video dir 
$video = 'ww.flv'; 
//where to save the image 
$image = 'image.jpg'; 
//time to take screenshot at 
$interval = 5; 
//screenshot size 
$size = '640x480'; */
//ffmpeg command 
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i ww.flv -ss 00:00:14 -f image2 -vframes 1 out.png";
exec($cmd);
```

why my thumbnail not created?
please help me!
thanks a lot...

Comment: Try to set `$ffmpeg = `'<YOUR_ABSOLUTE_FILESYSTEM_PATH>/ffmpeg-2.5.3/ffmpeg-2.5.3';`

Comment: Think about what command is being created in `$cmd`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ffmpeg-php to create thumbnail of video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911797/ffmpeg-php-to-create-thumbnail-of-video)